# Tmux is displaying strange characters

Tags: tmux, character-encoding

I'm having an issue with tmux where it's displaying these strange characters

[image]

I've found a few posts the seemed to be talking about the same issue and they suggested that I need to change my character encoding to utf-8 but I did that already.

[Here's my .tmux.config file.](https://gist.github.com/ryanstull/4e4e7853349790c1e85bdf0c9ac36132)

And here's the output of `locale`

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Also my shell is zsh, and I'm running on Ubuntu 17.10 just fyi.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: _Which_ characters are the "strange" ones?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you are using a font which does not render the unicode charaters properly. Even if you use UTF-8 (or other full unicode encoding) you still need to use a font which contains characters (or reasonable fallback characters) that you want to show properly. If you are natively speaking English and use only ASCII characters then it is surprising to see unicode ones being displayed somewhere, however that still can happen (for example, when displaying some external text containing non-ASCII characters).

Most fonts do not support ALL of unicode characters as there is a great number of them, however you might want to check out this [website](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) and [this one](http://czyborra.com/unifont) as they seem to provide more information about these fonts, which I recommend you install and see if this fixes your rendering.